# Если нет картинки - показать другую

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

Как можно сделать так, чтобы если картинка по запросу не найдена, показать другую (blank.png)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location /img {
    try_files $uri /img/blank.png;
}
```

Comment: Сделал так:

    location /images/map {
        try_files $uri images/map/blank.png;
    }

Теперь при любом запросе картинки выдает 404 xD

Comment: Забыл про слеш, но все равно при любом запросе выдает 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Нашел проблему :)

Comment: А как же поделиться решением?

Comment: Проблема не в вашем примере, а в настройках nginx :) rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/images/map/default.gif" - вот такая ошибка была)